# Aggregate or pool null vectors into largest null vector?

Tags: c++, g++, pool, c++03

I have a C++ header-only template class that uses a null vector (the string of 0's). The length of the string is determined by the template parameter (its an [HKDF](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5869.txt) implementation, and the length depends on the underlying hash digest size).

```
template < class HASH >
class HKDF
{
  ...
  private:
    typedef byte NullVector[HASH::DIGESTSIZE];
    static const NullVector m_vec;
};
```

The various `NullVector` can be aggregated, and all instantiated classes can use the `NullVector` of the largest digest size. For example, MD5 has a 16 byte digest size, and SHA-512 has a 64-byte digest size. So the toolchain could produce one vector of 64-bytes, and then all classes, like MD5, SHA-1, Whirlpool and SHA-512 could use it.

This is similar to string pooling, but I don't expect the compiler or linker to to make this observation or see this pattern (but I could be wrong). So I would like to give the tools a hint.

Is it possible to tell the compiler or linker to aggregate or pool `NullVectors`, and only output the largest in the final binary? If so, how?

I regularly work with MSVC, GCC, ICC and Clang. I'm especially interested in doing it for GCC-compatible compilers because it covers a majority of use cases. So I'm happy to use a GCC-specific extension, if needed.

---

Here's some more of the back story... Iterative hashes, like MD5, SHA1 through SHA512 and Whirlpool have a fixed block size. For those hashes, sharing a 64-byte array of 0's should be fine. I've never seen a iterative hash with a block size larger than 64-bytes, but I need to be mindful of it.

Recursive hashes, like SHA-3, don't have a block size *per se*. I'm not even sure how to make classic HMAC's and HKDF's work for SHA3 and other recursive hashes.

You can do equivalent things with iterative and recursive hashes, though. You can obviously digest a message. But as a more complex example, an HMAC has to add an `ipad` and `opad` to an iterative hash due to extension attacks, but you can produce a keyed digest or auth tag. For recursive hashes, you just concatenate the key with the message to produce the keyed digest or auth tag. There's no need for the inner or outer padding with a recursive hash.

Comment: So you want a custom allocator?

Comment: Not the way you've defined the template. Note that each time you instantiate the template with a different type (`HASH`), a new static `m_vec` will be created. So, `HKDF<Hash1>` and `HKDF<Hash2>` will not share `m_vec` if `Hash1` and `Hash2` are different types.

Comment: You basically want to have only one instance of NullVector (strange name, by the way. It is NOT a vector as it is usually understood) of the biggest size per the whole application?

Comment: It cannot be done by the compiler, because the final size of that storage is affected by more than a single translation unit. Thus the linker needs to do this, but I doubt that any linker is able to do such an optimisation (though I could be wrong here), regarding the missing information of type etc. You could try to use some library to read and write the object files yourself, but this will be a lot of work. Do you really need to save that space?

Comment: *"You basically want to have only one instance of NullVector"* - yes. There's no reason to have a string of 0's in the BSS for `HKDF<SHA1>`, a different string of 0's in the BSS for  `HKDF<SHA256>`, yet another string of 0's for  `HKDF<SHA512>`. By the way, what would you like me to call it? We've called the string of 0's a null vector for at least 20 years (when I was in college, on the east coast in the US). But I'd be happy to change terminology for you if it makes it easier to answer the question.

Comment: @jww, arguably 20 years ago NullVector was a good name. However, nowadays in C++ world vector is uniformely known to be std::vector<>. Null vector would be something like std::vector<nullptr_t>. I do not see how what you want to do can be automatically done. As far as compiler/linker are concerned, those arrays are indpendent members of their classess, with no relationship to each other whatsoever. You might want to declare a global variable with the size of biggest array, and than reference it in your classess. (with static assert is the size is less than what you need).

Comment: The difficulty is finding out the maximum size. Although not perfect, is it acceptable to hardcode a usual maximum size (such as 256)? And any uses of a larger size can revert to the inefficient way (so at least code will still work)

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I have to agree that "null vector" is a misleading name, as "null" and "vector" both have different common uses in C++. You really just want to pool arrays of the same constant value together.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution that gets you closer but you will still have to decide what the largest size ought to be:

Edit: Updated due to `c++03` tag. Previous code required c++11.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>

struct NullContainer                                                            
{                                                                               
    static const size_t LARGEST_SIZE = 1024 ;                               
    typedef unsigned char LargeNullVector[LARGEST_SIZE] ;                             
    static const LargeNullVector m_vec ;                                        
} ;             

const NullContainer::LargeNullVector NullContainer::m_vec = {0} ;

template < class HASH >                                                         
class HKDF : public NullContainer                                               
{                                                                               
} ;                                                                                              

int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
    assert( &HKDF<int>::m_vec == &HKDF<char>::m_vec ) ;                         
    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Of course, you may want to use [private inheritance](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance#priv-inherit-like-compos) in this case.

Comment: Whatever do you mean? See [this](http://cpp.sh/74xh). Okay so I was missing `cstdlib` header. But did you use c++11 compiler flag? :D

Comment: Yeah, I thought about `static const size_t LARGEST_SIZE = 1024` (its C++03, sorry about that). There's no guarantee any size is large enough now a days because of recursive hash functions. And that type of change kind of breaks from Eronen and Krawczyk's specification, which could make it harder to understand and/or audit. (Those are security engineering requirements I try to stay mindful of). Hence the reason I wanted to aggregate or pool whatever was present.

Comment: @jww All good points. I understand your issue but I don't think there is a way to do this in standard C++.

Comment: @crayzeewulf - *"I don't think there is a way to do this in standard C++"* - yes, agreed. I was hoping GCC provided an extension to do it.